# VBA:Copy result and paste in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I fullfilled  all requirements but i would like to have a my result in another excel sheet rather showing the result in the same sheet.

Here is my code:

```
Dim filterrange As Range

Set filterrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(2, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)  ' get columns e.g. name, state, etc.

filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array("GBR" _
        , "MAD", "NCE", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="Yes" ' activeconnect
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="=" ' clustername
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "<>*@sca.ama.com*", Operator:=xlAnd ' e-mail
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
         "Madrid", "Sophia-antipolis"), Operator:=xlFilterValues


For Each cell In filterrange.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

If Cells(cell.Row, 24) = "" Then
   Select Case Cells(cell.Row, 11).Value
      Case "NCE"
        Cells(cell.Row, 24) = "nceccm.iis.net"
      Case "MAD"
        Cells(cell.Row, 24) = "mucpccm.iis.net"
     End Select
End If
Next cell

     Dim ws as worksheet
       set ws = worksheets.add("Sheet2") after:=Activesheet
        ws.name = "abc"
        ws.copy
      worksheets("abc").paste

   end sub
```

The result should dipslay in another sheet(sheet2), but for me its showing the result in sheet1 and sheet2, the actual data must remain unchanged in sheet1 when we excute the code the result must be displayed in sheet2. can anyone please help me out.

Comment: Please be more specific. What results do you want in a new sheet? Do you simply wish to copy the existing sheet to a new sheet? Do you want only the changed cells to show up in a different sheet or all the filtered cells?

Comment: Have you searched StackOverflow for similar questions already?  I'd be very surprised if your question hasn't already been answered.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I want all the actual output should be displayed in a new sheet, but my code is showing same results in sheet1 and sheet2. I want the actual data be remain unchanged in sheet1 only the output should show up in new sheet(i.e sheet2). One more thing is, about my code  if i excute the code multiple times every time its opening a new sheet( i.e sheet2,sheet3.....so on). No matter how many times we excute it should displayed in sheet2 only.(it must refresh automatically when we excute more times)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Example()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Dim filterrange As Range

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Worksheet.Name = "abc" Then
        Set ws2 = Worksheet
    End If
Next Worksheet

If ws2 Is Nothing Then
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)
    ws2.Name = "abc"
End If

ws1.Activate
Set filterrange = ws1.Cells(2, ws1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)  ' get columns e.g. name, state, etc.

filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array("GBR" _
        , "MAD", "NCE", "="), Operator:=xlFilterValues
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="Yes" ' activeconnect
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="=" ' clustername
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        "<>*@sca.amadeus.com*", Operator:=xlAnd ' e-mail
filterrange.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=Array( _
         "Madrid", "Sophia-antipolis"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

For Each cell In filterrange.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows

If Cells(cell.Row, 24) = "" Then
   Select Case Cells(cell.Row, 11).Value
      Case "NCE"
        Cells(cell.Row, 24) = "nceiptccm.iis.amadeus.net"
      Case "MAD"
        Cells(cell.Row, 24) = "muciptccm.iis.amadeus.net"
     End Select
End If
Next cell

filterrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
ws2.Activate
ws2.Range("a1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

ws1.Activate
On Error Resume Next
ws1.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0


End Sub
```

Comment: the modification which you have done to my code is working but the thing here is , I need only the ouput must be displayed in sheet2, the raw or actual data must remain unchanged in sheet1, rather its showing the same results in sheet1 and sheet2. I need only the result to be populated in sheet2.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the filter to be turned off on Sheet1 once it is done?

Comment: Exactly. The result which would come from sheet1 must display in sheet2 only. Even if i excute the code multiple times every time its opening a new sheet (say sheet3,sheet4 ...so on) and displaying empty rows. I dont need this. All i want is the result should display in sheet2 if i excute multiple times.

Comment: I updated it to look for sheet "abc" and use it if it finds it, but if it fails to find "abc" it will create a new sheet and use that.  I then added a bit at the end that we clear the filter on the first page.